# count of files only in a list

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I have a txt file that has the list of files an folders per each line. I would like to have the only count of files not folders.

```
Count=$(cat list.txt | wc -l)
```

will give me the total count.

Comment: show us a sample of the file's data.

Comment: `count=$(perl -nlE '-f&&$n++}{say$n' < list.txt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the type of each file in a loop:

```
count=0
IFS=$'\n' # so spaces in filenames don't cause a problem
for i in $(< list.txt); do
    if [ -f "$i" ]
    then count=$((count + 1))
    fi
done
```

Comment: Certainly this would work if the files actually exist, but it wouldn't be very useful if they didn't, or if they were simply in a different directory. Granted, not really sure what the OP needs here.

Comment: Is `count=$((count + 1))` clearer than `((count++))`?

Comment: @ghoti Just style difference

Answer (score 0):

below is very straight forward

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | wc -l
```

Comment: I get this, find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: Try this   `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d  | wc -l`

Comment: Yes. Now how could I modify it to show me the count of listing within a list.txt file?

Comment: You have to write a loop and iterate. as mentioned in the answer above to my answer :)